# Symfony2 - Entity Slug in route

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, routes, slug

I am using SF2 Framework and I want to implement a routing like this one :

`mywebsite.com/en/customer/sensiolab/employee/johndoe/statistics`

where "sensiolab" and "johndoe" are slugs.

Right now, I created global Controller routes like this one:

```
/**
 * Statistics controller.
 *
 * @Route("/customer/{customer_slug}/employee/{employee_slug}/statistics")
 * @ParamConverter("customer", class="AppBundle:Customer", options={"id" = "customer_slug", "repository_method" = "findOneBySlug"})
 * @ParamConverter("employee", class="AppBundle:Employee", options={"id" = "employee_slug", "repository_method" = "findOneBySlug"})
 */
class StatisticsController extends Controller {
```

It's working really well but it means that I need to specify the customer_slug and employee_slug in almost every link and pass this information in every controllers...

Is there a solution to implement this route structure easily. Is it possible to do something like I did for the _locale (which is working pretty well)?

Thank you,

Comment: And what is the thing that you did for `_locale`? ;-)

Comment: I followed this cookbook :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html
But the problem is if someone send a link to another person, then I would have to create the session variable but I don't want to do that in every controllers.

Comment: So I think that you should explain what is the exact expected result.